# Typo in the homework closing reason

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons

Sorry, not really a discussion topic, but I was unsure how else to get this fixed.

---

When voting to close, selecting a community specific reason, the first option's text is (emphasis by me)

> This question does not meet the standards for homework questions as spelled out in the relevant meta posts. For more information, see our policy on homework **question** and the general FAQ.

This should be question**s**.

---

Upon fixing the issue this question can be deleted.

Comment: thanks for bringing this to our attention, unfortunately we can't edit this reason, we could add new custom one and deactivate this one but I think it will be better if some CM will have a look at it so I edited your q with status review to bring it to their attention

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this - I also gave it a title "Problematic homework question" but if that doesn't capture what the close reason is for, let me know and I can adjust it.

As a note, y'all might consider improving the guidance for your close reasons in general - [I have a guide about how to do this on MSE here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362581/should-we-update-clarify-our-help-center-with-respect-to-other-sites-and-teams/362584#362584), if you're interested - essentially, there are many fields that can be customized for close voters, the asker, and viewers of the closed question to better target the abilities of those people to act to improve the question.

You're no longer tied to a single statement, so if y'all want to do this, feel free to start a discussion here on meta and, once you have the wording you want, status-review tag it.